# How to rename a method name from Intellisense?

Tags: vb.net, methods

Does anyone know how? I'm trying to make a method that the intellisense shows another name instead of the name you ta the method. example:

**The code looks like this:**

```
Public Shared Sub Anything(ByVal blablabla....)
    (...)
End Sub
```

**And I want to auto-complete the VisualStudio menu be like:**

```
Async
Alalala
Anymethod
Anything   - Like these
Basic
```

**On mouse hover:**

instead of...

```
Public Shared Sub Namespace.Anything(ByVal blablablbal....)
This is the summary...
```

put it:

```
Anything <expression>
This is the summary...
```

-or-
    Sub Anything
    This is the summary...

Any ideas? thx...

Comment: If my answer doesn't cover what you're asking (and I'm not entirely sure it does, now I'm looking again), could you clarify your question a little more please?

Comment: On your answer , it did not solve my problem , I did this procedure and added a description under my method , that's not what I wanted, wanted to set the first line tooltip only the method name ... thanks

Comment: Fair enough!  I assume you've got a good reason as to _why_ you'd want your methods to show up with different names?  Once intellisense has inserted it, does it actually compile properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooooo, I hope my answer isn't too vague. I'd love to help you igure it out either way.

Basically - you have to override the XML Documentation that Intellisense uses, in order to MAP a new MethodName to a Differently-Named method within your assembly.

---

Intellisense uses an XML Skeleton to define the different properties of what you see. That Skeleton typically looks something like this:

```
<CodeElement type="Function">
  <Template>
    <summary/>
    <param/>
    <returns/>
    <remarks/>
  </Template>
  <CompletionList>
    <exception cref=""/>
    <include file="" path=""/>
    <param name=""/>
    <remarks/>
    <returns/>
    <summary/>
  </CompletionList>
</CodeElement>
```

You can use this template to generate the Intellisense data you're looking for. In real-life application, this would look something like this:

```
''' <summary>
'''
''' </summary>
''' <param name="str"></praram>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function Anything(ByVal str As String) As String
      Try
    ...
```

Now, this template ***is Editable***
The Visual Basic compiler generates an XML document for your assembly with all the XML comments defined in the code. The compiler will also resolve symbols used in cref, permission, and name attributes, as well as file references in include elements.
The generated file doesn't show your commented members hierarchically. Rather, it is a flat list. It includes a unique ID string for each definition that allows the comments to be mapped back to their definitions in code (see Code Snippet below).
In this case, the string is **M:Namespace.Anything(System.String)**. **M** stands for *method*, **Namespace** specifies the *path*, **System.String** the parameter type.

THIS is where you would override the NAME of the Method that INTELLISENSE sees, without effecting the actual Method itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<doc>
<assembly>
<name>AnyLib</name>
</assembly>
<members>
...
<member name="M:Namespace.Anything(System.String)">
  <summary>Does something</summary>
  <param name="str">str to pass into method</param>
  <returns>A string</returns>
</member>
...
</members>
</doc>
```

You can generate the XML documentation file using either the command-line compiler or through the Visual Studio interface. If you are compiling with the command-line compiler, use options /doc or /doc+. That will generate an XML file by the same name and in the same path as the assembly. To specify a different file name, use /doc:file.
If you are using the Visual Studio interface, there's a setting that controls whether the XML documentation file is generated. To set it, double-click My Project in Solution Explorer to open the Project Designer. Navigate to the Compile tab. Find "Generate XML documentation file" at the bottom of the window, and make sure it is checked. By default this setting is on. It generates an XML file using the same name and path as the assembly

In short - yes, it is possible, but very cumbersome and makes re-using your code very difficult. Check this link for a more detailed overview:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're talking about [XML Comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172652.aspx).  Without comments:

[image]

With comments:

[image]

And Intellisense then also displays the parameter information as you get to each parameter:

[image]